# Load *.so with JNA on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jna, .so

I'm working on a `Android Service`, which communicate with hardware & applications. I am using a native library to access hardware (**libTemp.so**). I tested this lib on `windows` & `ubuntu` with a java program using JNA.

> temperatureHardware = (TempNative) Native.loadLibrary("libTemp.so", TempNative.class);

This is how I connect the `*.so` lib with the `TempNative object`. When I try this on Android, I get as follow.

`W/linker: /data/app/com.example.kube.tempsystemservice-YUkS9udICA7GsJhTA8fG4A==/lib/arm/libjnidispatch.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "libjnidispatch.so"`

`Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libTemp.so': Native library (android-arm/liblibTemp.so.so) not found in resource path (.)`

is this because **service can't find the lib** file?

I add the lib file as follow...

[image: lib file location image]

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54663679/8034839

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using the library name without the extension.

```
temperatureHardware = (TempNative) Native.loadLibrary("libTemp", TempNative.class);
```

Comment: It gave the issue like this : `Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'Temp': Native library (android-arm/libTemp.so) not found in resource path (.)`

Comment: You might try passing the absolute path to the library, including filename.