# Android JNA UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/xxx/libjnidispatch.so) not found

Tags: android, jna, libvirt

Hey I am trying to set up a android studio project with JNA and libvirt java bindings.

This is what the project structure looks like so far.

[image] however the solution did not work for me

This is being tested not he emulator so far and the arm binaries have not been imported yet.

When trying to use Connect method in the libvirt java bindings I get this error.

There is a very similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305914/setting-up-jna-in-android-studio)

```
11-18 23:54:37.584 4182-4182/com.local.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: com.local.test, PID: 4182
                                                           java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/android-x86/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path (.)
                                                               at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:1039)
                                                               at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:999)
                                                               at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:191)
                                                               at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:625)
                                                               at org.libvirt.jna.Libvirt.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                                                               at org.libvirt.Library.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                                                               at org.libvirt.Connect.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.local.haris.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Notes:
Android studio 3.0
Do not have the c++ SDK installed (didn't think I needed to since I am not compiling binaries)
If am unsure if the libvirt java jar works on android. I tried to find information about this but failed to do. If someone could comment on this it would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you targeting Android device with x86 platform or ARM-based platform?

Answer (score 6):

although many days have passed since the question arose I found that adding the following will resolve the issue (of course use version of your choice):

```
implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0@aar'
```

Comment: There are duplicate class errors at build-time. [Another response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68077436/16595881) to this question provides more detail.

Answer (score 5):

Include the `libjnidispatch.so` shared library for all the Android ABIs that your project supports.

- Navigate to [JNA libraries](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/releases).
- Under Version 4.5.0, download the zip archive
- Unzip the package, navigate to `jna-4.5.0/dist/` directory. `libjnidispatch.so` for different ABIs can be extracted from respective jar file. The mapping is as below illustrated in below table.

  ```
  | JNA ABI             | Android ABI   |
  | ------------------- | ------------- |
  | android-aarch64.jar | arm64-v8a     |
  | android-armv7.jar   | armeabi-v7a   |
  | android-x86-64.jar  | x86_64        |
  | android-x86.jar     | x86           |
  ```
- Put the `libjnidispatch.so` into the mapped Android ABI folder, for example, `arm64-v8a`, `armeabi-v7a`, `x86` and `x86_64`.

Answer (score 1):

koby hershkovitz's answer of "just add @aar" results in duplicate classes:

```
Duplicate class com.sun.jna.AltCallingConvention found in modules jetified-jna-5.8.0 (net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0) and jetified-jna-5.8.0-runtime (net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0)
Duplicate class com.sun.jna.Callback found in modules jetified-jna-5.8.0 (net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0) and jetified-jna-5.8.0-runtime (net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0)
Duplicate class com.sun.jna.Callback$UncaughtExceptionHandler found in modules jetified-jna-5.8.0 (net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0) and jetified-jna-5.8.0-runtime (net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0)
Duplicate class com.sun.jna.CallbackParameterContext found in modules jetified-jna-5.8.0 (net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0) and jetified-jna-5.8.0-runtime (net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0)
Duplicate class com.sun.jna.CallbackProxy found in modules jetified-jna-5.8.0 (net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0) and jetified-jna-5.8.0-runtime (net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0)
...
```

To fix this, use @aar on whatever library needs jna as well, otherwise gradle will pull the JNA library in twice.

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest JNAs
Especially the aar

```
implementation "net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.9.0@aar"
```

Then add the necessary dependencies to your resource path.
If you need to add*.so files, download the relevant jar and extract it.
For example, if you are missing android-x86,

1. download the jar from here.
   https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/dist/android-x86-64.jar
2. Extract the jar file

   [image: How the jar and the extract looks like]
3. Copy and paste extracted directory to the resource path
   Example Resource path :

   ```
   sourceSets {
       main {
           jniLibs.srcDirs += ["$projectDir/src/debug/jniLibs"]
       }

       debug {
           jniLibs.srcDirs += ["$projectDir/src/debug/jniLibs"]
       }

       release {
           jniLibs.srcDirs += ["$projectDir/src/release/jniLibs"]
       }
   }
   ```
4. Clean and rebuild the project